# Proof that $\binom{2N-1}{N} = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \binom{N+j-1}{j}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes

This is part of a stochastic excercise. The sample solution states $$\binom{2N-1}{N}$$, but my solution is $$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \binom{N+j-1}{j}$$.
I calculated both for some N, like N=2, N=5 and both solutions provided the same result. Acutally I am pretty sure that my solution is equal to the one given, but I am unable to proof it. The main struggle is that $j$ is part of both entries of the binomial coefficient, what makes it hard to use the defintion of the binomial coefficient with the factorial.
Like I said, it's not like I know that this is true, but I am pretty sure. But if someone got an counterexample or can proof that this is not the same I would be thankful too.

Comment: Note that $\binom{N+j-1}j=\binom{N+j-1}{N-1}$.

Comment: and apply the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, note that, $ \left(\forall j\in\mathbb{N}\right) $, we have : \begin{aligned}\binom{n-1+j}{j}&=\binom{n-1+j}{n-1}\\ &=\binom{n+j}{n}-\binom{n-1-j}{n}\end{aligned}

Thus : \begin{aligned} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1+j}{j}}&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left[\binom{n+j}{n}-\binom{n-1-j}{n}\right]}\\ &=\binom{2n-1}{n} \end{aligned}